# Using Multiline Regular Expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex, json, python-2.7

I am using regular expressions in Python to search through a page source, and find all the json information in the javascript. Specifically an example would look something like this:

```
var fooData = {
    id: 123456789,
    name : "foo bar",
    country_name: "foo",
    country_is_eu: null,
    foo_bars: null,
    foo_email: null,
    foo_rate: 1.0,
    foo_id: 0987654321
};
```

I'm fairly new to understanding all there is to know about regular expressions, and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. I can get some individual lines, but I'm not completely sure of how to use re.MULTILINE. This is the code I have so right now:

```
prog = re.compile('[var ]?\w+ ?= ?{[^.*]+\n};', re.MULTILINE)
vars = prog.findall(text)
```

Why is this not working?

To be more clear, I really need it to match everything in between these brackets like this:

```
var fooData = {

};
```

So, essentially I can't figure out a way to match every line except one that looks like this:

```
};
```

Comment: checkout [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14000225/1006989), I updated it, maybe you'd like to give it a try

Comment: Yes thank you for helping me! I didn't realize that it was as simple as `[^}]+`, I did not know you could do that.

Comment: There's a built in `json` module that is useful. It sounds like you should be using that instead of regex.

Comment: Obviously when i have the entire page source, to parse the json i have to find it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for not including the brackets:

```
(?<=var fooData = {)[^}]+(?=};)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your diligence in helping me even after I got it to work. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

When you're not sure, always consult the documentation (it's quite good for Python).

The [multi-line mode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) makes regular expressions beginning with a caret (^) and ending with a ($) to match the beginning and end of each respective line (where a "line" is whatever immediately follows a newline character `\n`).

It looks like you are already accounting for this by having `\n`s at the beginning and end of your regex and you are using the `findall()` function.

Comment: I'm using `findall()` because I'm looking for all instances of the stated pattern, and I've already read the documentation.

Comment: @yentup `findall()` matches ALL instances of the regex and so if you have `\n` at the beginning and end of your regular expression then multiline mode is useless.

Comment: I know how `findall()` works, I'm not stupid. I'm trying to find everything like that in the entire page, the multiline is only for finding all the random information in between the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Turns out multiline mode was not even needed, I just matched all lines that didn't end in a `;` in between the brackets. I also slightly modified the regex for finding the brackets and such, here is my code:

```
re.findall('(?:var )?\w+[ ]?=[ ]?{\n(?:.+(?!(?<=;))\n)+};', text)
```

Thanks to X.Jacobs, I simplified (and fixed) my code to this:

```
re.findall('(?:var )?\w+\s*=\s*{[^;]+};', text)
```